# Добавить scroll

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как лучше сделать.
Есть div-container куда добавляются div и они могут внутри блока передвигаться
,сейчас передвигаются только внутри блока,а изменять размер могут и за пределами блока.Мне нужно чтобы когда размер уходил за блок,появлялся скролл и блоки уходили ниже. Скролл то я сделал,но при изменении размер блок уходит все равно за пределы. Вот наработка

```
#container {
  box-shadow: 4px 0px 18px -1px #0000ff;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y:scroll
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/japfdL1t/2/
Подскажите,как поступить

Answer (score 1):

В jquery-ui у ресайза есть две дивные опции:
1.maxHeight 
2.maxWidth

```
dynDiv.resizable({
      ghost: true,
      maxHeight: $('#container').height(),
      maxWidth: $('#container').width(),
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/japfdL1t/3/

Comment: Мне нужно,что бы скролл появился(

Comment: Это аналог containment: 'parent' ,который почему то не правильно работает)